# how to check the null property of a charfield null=true before migration?

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I want to implement a solution to the following problem :
I would like to check before any migrations if my new charfield model fields have the attribute null set to false. If not i do want to stop the migrations and trigger a warning to inform the developer about it.
How could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is made in the source of django you need to over write it,

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    #Your logic
```

other way of solving this problem is to set

```
class yourModel(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
```

Comment: I can't change my models because I have to change them all but what I want is to force the developers not to add charfields with null=true and if it exists then I alert them before the migration without making any specific class